# Mongo DB is not updated by id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

i'm trying to update mongo db document with mongo db driver on node js, the log show that it's updated but the data is not updated, i'm trying to get the data to get updated with id document and the document is not updated, but when i use another field as a variable to search the document, the document is updated.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://192.168.1.200:27017/";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("monitoring");
  var myquery = { _id : "62e5e171f38e161d6e905772" };
  var newvalues = { $set: { status: "1" } };
  dbo.collection("hosts").updateOne(myquery, newvalues, function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 document updated");
    db.close();
  });
});
```

Picture of the data:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_id` property in MongoDB is not of type **String**, it's of type **ObjectId**. Try this:

```
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;   
...
const myquery = { _id : new ObjectId("62e5e171f38e161d6e905772") };
```